# How to disable Cash on Delivery for Downloadable products on Opencart 2.1.0.1

Tags: opencart2.x

How to disable Cash on Delivery for Downloadable products on Opencart 2.1.0.1?

I want just Bank transfer and Credit card pay options for Downloadable products.

Comment: Please find third party extension for that. http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=download/download

Comment: Thanks for your advice, but I want to solve the problem without buying a third part extension.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the simple solution. Just try this one. Change file `catalog/model/payment/cod.php`

Replace `if ($status) {` with `if ($status && $this->cart->hasShipping()) {` and it will work.